# Creating controlled trials with overlapping uncorrelated conditions

Tags: regression, experiment-design, random-allocation

Let's say I have a set of students, and a set of learning materials for an upcoming test.  My goal is to run an experiment to see which learning materials are correlated with better scores on the test via multiple linear regression.

I'd like to show as many students as possible as many of the learning materials as possible, while minimizing collinearity in order to get accurate data about each individual learning material.  Is there an established method to create subsets of students for each learning material, which satisfies this requirement?